# change navigationbar on only one view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have set a custom navigationbar in my appdelegate. You can see the code over here.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But now I'm working with the eventkit framework. What I want is when I go to eventdetails, that I get the standard navbar layout.So without the image.

```
EKEventViewController *vc = [[EKEventViewController alloc] init];
[vc.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
vc.event = [dataSource eventAtIndexPath:indexPath];
vc.allowsEditing = YES;
[calendar.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I've tried the following but it is not working.
Any help?

Comment: Did you try putting the [vc.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] command into the viewWillAppear of the EKEventViewController class itself?

Comment: You can't access this class? This is a class inside the eventKit framework

Comment: How is it not working? Does the image not change?

Comment: No the image is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

you can do one thing, take the screenshot of one viewController with default navigation bar , just crop only navigation bar area i.e. make image of 320 x 44 size.

when you want again your by default navigation bar , that time use this cropped image as background of navigation bar ,add following code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultNavbar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

again when you navigate to another viewController having custom Navimage then again draw nav image by help of your custom image code i.e.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```